# Bus ticketing reservation systems

Tags: php, mysql

I am planning to make an online bus ticket reservation systems . In this, the ticket agent as well as the online user can book the tickets available . But I am stuck while I am building my flow chart . Buses with same numbers can go to and fro journey,ie a bus with number AS 1234 can go to X and Y in both direction  . So how I will be able to search the bus from X and Y only,because that bus will be entered for both direction in database . Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding an extra attribute like "running". Set it to accept NULL also. If its a bus with bidirectional traffic., When the bus with bus number-AS4532 is running from X->Y, mark attribute "running='to'" in that record. If its vice-versa set it as "running="fro"'. if its unidirectional bus, mark attribute  as "N/A".

So you can do something like,

```
SELECT seats_free FROM Buses WHERE busNo="AS1234" and place1="X" and place2="Y" and running="to";
SELECT seats_free FROM Buses WHERE busNo="AS1234" and place1="X" and place2="Y" and running="fro";
SELECT seats_free FROM Buses WHERE busNo="AS1221" and place1="X" and place2="Y" and running="N/A";
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple, give each bus a unique identifier in your database. Like the number the bus company gave it (usually on a sticker on the back of the bus) or even it's VIN number could work.

Comment: Suppose the bus with number AS1234(unique) goes to X to Y and vice versa. So if I search buses on dated 2011-14-12 from Y to X only and another person search bus for same date but from X to Y, it will show that bus (AS1234) ! Because I have entered that bus number for both the ways !

Comment: Assuming that each bus drives a specific route, attach the route(s) to the bus. Like route A: From X To Y. Route B: From Y To X. Then use that route to filter for the proper bus.